# tag-it autocomplete return data type issue

Tags: jquery-ui, tag-it

Can I get array of objects from assignedTags.
Example:

```
var data = {
  label : example,
  id : 1,
  name : example_1
}
```

Auto complete shows `label` , but on `select`, when I call `assignedTags` I want to send array of objects back, example :

```
[{label : example,id : 1,name : example_1}, {label : example,id : 2,name : example_2}, ...]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use concat() to combine all of your arrays.
So its `array1.concat(array2).`

Then use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the array into a JSON object.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array1);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Jquery Tag-IT.js returns the selected items from textbox in a array for example : ["text1, text2"] etc which are labels. I want this instead       [{label : example,id : 1,name : example_1}, {label : example,id : 2,name : example_2}, ...]

Answer (score 0):

push into an array somewhat like this :-

```
var array = [];
var data={label: example};
array.push(data);
```